# Android - The constructor ImageAdapter(Tab2SalonActivity)is undefined

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-gridview

I'm new on Android, I have one problem implementing GridView on "extends Fragment".

**Tab2SalonActivity.java**

```
public class Tab2SalonActivity extends Fragment
{
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            final View root= inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_two_salon, container, false);

            GridView gridview = (GridView) root.findViewById(R.id.gridView);

            gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));//Line error

            gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                        int position, long id) {     
                }
            });

            return root;
        }
    }
```

**ImageAdapter.java**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }//continue...
```

¿How I can solve this issue?

The Error it's:

> "The constructor ImageAdapter(Tab2SalonActivity) is undefined"

I don't know how i can defined on constructor, always i have errors, please, help me!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

to

```
gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));
```

The constructor expects `Context` as param. But `this` does not refer to a valid context

Comment: Thanks for the info, dont worry, i accept your answer.